# Библиотека визуализации, кто знает такую

Tags: java, поиск-библиотек

Всем привет, 
Кто-то подскажет где найти или купить такую библиотеку визуализации аудио?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию - это офф-топик.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Вообще-то существует метка "поиск-библиотек", не так ли?

Comment: @Miron но в справке чёрным по белому написано, что такие вопросы лучше не задавать.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9492/3380 - такие вопросы вполне приемлемы.

Comment: https://github.com/goxr3plus/Java-Audio-Wave-Spectrum-API 1 минута поиска

Comment: @maestro это личное мнение одного из модераторов. Но как показывает опыт, они между собой не очень-то и договориться могут. Так что зафиксированные в справке правила мне видятся более авторитетным источником.